# error : You are not allowed to upload code while setting upstream

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to set the upstream for one of the branch in gitlab using `git push` command

```
git push --set-upstream origin hotfix_master_$CI_COMMIT_SHA
```

here are the set of commands which I'm executing

```
    - echo $CI_COMMIT_SHA   // echo commit SHA 
    - echo "${GITLAB_USER_NAME}" // echo user name 
    - echo "${GITLAB_USER_EMAIL}" // echo user mail 
    - git checkout hotfix_master // get the current working tree/workspace for hotfix_master
    - git pull // pull the latest changes 
    - git checkout -b hotfix_master_$CI_COMMIT_SHA // create new branch from source as hotfix_master 
    - git fetch // get refs from remote and commit in local 
    - git push --set-upstream origin hotfix_master_$CI_COMMIT_SHA  // associate remote branches
```

Getting following error :

> remote: You are not allowed to upload code. fatal: unable to access
> 'https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@gitlab.com/xxx/xxx-project.git/':
> The requested URL returned error: 403

have already created the personal access token and was working fine . issue started when started creating branch from the commit_sha . not sure why ? I have checked the token is not expired .
from local command prompt , everything works

```
$ git push --set-upstream origin hotfix_master_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote:
remote: To create a merge request for hotfix_master_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, visit:
remote:   https://gitlab.com/xxx/xxx-project/-/merge_requests/new?merge_request%5Bsource_branch%5D=hotfix_master_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
remote:
To https://gitlab.com/xxx/xxx-project.git
 * [new branch]      hotfix_master_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx -> hotfix_master_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Branch 'hotfix_master_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' set up to track remote branch 'hotfix_master_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' from 'origin'.
```

not able to understand why it is failing from gitlab CI pipeline. please suggest

**EDIT 1**

[image]

**EDIT 2**

I have created now new token "gitlab-ci-token" as the error indicates that, it is trying to use the token named "gitlab-ci-token" still not working

[image]

Comment: `git push --set-upstream` sets an upstream *as a side effect*. Its main effect is to upload new commits. You—or rather, your CI job—does not have permission to do that. If it is supposed to have permission, check the permissions you or your admin gave it.

Comment: I am the only one who is admin/maintainer of the git project and I have given all the permission . see EDIT 1 . i am using gitlab_token1

Comment: It says that token is never used . do I need to mention username/password in git push command ?

Comment: I haven't used the GitLab CI, but you'll need to set up whatever access rights are required (ssh or https), using whatever facilities GitLab-CI provides to set these. In general, if you are using ssh, you must set up ssh; if you are using https, you must create the credentials and set up a credential helper that produces them when Git runs it. (Remember that Git itself does no authentication: it relies on other programs for this.)

Comment: literally not getting why it is not working. I have created new token "gitlab-ci-token" and given all access . still the error . why the push is not working ???

Comment: You can embed the user name and token in the URL (as in KamilCuk's answer) but that's *generally* considered unwise since they're now visible in plain-text in files viewable by everyone. Then again, if your available alternative is to put the user name and token in plain text in some *other* file *also* viewable by everyone, it's six-of-one half-a-dozen-of-the-other as they say. If you have a protected "secrets" type file, or some other way to *hide* these things, that's what you should use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> https://gitlab-ci-token:[MASKED]@...
> ```

The URL should be:

```
https://oauth2:<the_token>@...
```

The username is `oauth2`. Set the remote with `git remote set-url origin`.

Comment: Thanks. but where should I set this ? before git push command ? The error is coming exactly after git push command .

Comment: Before any command that connect to the remote and requires a password. `before git push command ?` Yes. Nowhere in your gitlab-ci you set the token anyway.